# Seeking CPAN module to create unique, sequenced file name

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm wondering if there's a CPAN module that will take a filename 'prefix' and return a file name that is currently unique in the system, in ascending sequence number order.

Thus if I'm about to open file foo for writing, I write to foo if it doesn't exist, or whichever of foo.1, foo.2 foo.3 ... doesn't yet exist.

It's not log rotation, and the files aren't temporary. I'm generating three separate streams from the same program, and want reasonable default behavior.  If the three streams (files) are foo, bar and blah, I don't want to force the user to specify new names for them, and I don't want to overwrite existing files.

Comment: What do you need this for? Do you want to create a temporary file?

Answer (score 2):

[File::Temp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aTemp) doesn't do the ascending part, but it does generate unique names.

Are you trying to do log rotation? There are modules to do that too.